# Clarification on 僕は落ちるのが怖い

Tags: meaning, usage

I have seen 僕は落ちるのが怖い  translated as "I am afraid to fall".   Could it also be used to mean "I am afraid to fail".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it certainly could.

> 「 [僕]{ぼく}は[落]{お}ちるのが[怖]{こわ}い。」

What this sentence means depends totally on the context.

> "I am afraid to ***fall***."

You are afraid of physically falling from a place of some height.

> "I am afraid to ***fail***."

You are taking an exam, auditioning for something, entering an election, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering.  Since  I have seen other situations where what you mise to fail like failing a test.